# view not updating after function changes value

Tags: angular

I have a function for deleting tags that adds to one array and deletes from another. This part is all working correctly, however when the new value is updated the view does not update:

```
accountDelete(id, name) {
    let accountsToAdd = this.userForm.value.accountsToAdd;
    const accountsToDelete = this.userForm.value.accountsToDelete;
    accountsToDelete.push(
        {
            id: id,
            name: name
        }
    );
    console.log(accountsToDelete);
    accountsToAdd = accountsToAdd.filter(account => account.id !== id);
    console.log(accountsToAdd);
}
```

and the template is:

```
<div class="tag-wrapper mt-3">
    <span class="badge tag" *ngFor="let account of userForm.value.accountsToAdd">
        <span class="tag-title">{{ account.name }}</span>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)="accountDelete(account.id, account.name)">
            <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

it should be noted since this involves a reactive form, I also tried:

```
this.userForm.patchValue({accountsToAdd: accountsToAdd.filter(account => account.id !== id)});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're carrying the results to variables inside accountDelete method, and must be carry to the scope

```
accountDelete(id, name) {
this.userForm.value.accountsToDelete.push(
    {
        id: id,
        name: name
    }
);
console.log(this.userForm.value.accountsToDelete);
this.userForm.value.accountsToAdd = this.userForm.value.accountsToAdd.filter(account => account.id !== id);
console.log(this.userForm.value.accountsToAdd);
```

}

Comment: This worked, thank you. I think I understand this. So since the variables are defined in the function, their values are limited to the scope of that function. Therefor I have to reassign the values to  class scope?